# Scheduled import of jsons in powe BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I have a restricted URL where every 10 mins. a json is incorporated. Accordingly, I have developed several R visuals in power BI Desktop by importing a sample json from this URL and thereby have published them in Power BI service ( in Power BI Pro trial version ).

How can I schedule import of the latest json every 10 minutes from this URL so that the reports so developed are automatically updated as per the latest json?

Answer (score 0):

Configuring scheduled refresh is [what you're looking for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-scheduled-refresh).

This will enable you to import the latest json every time you specify it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion...but power BI allows to schedule refresh every 30 minutes instead of every 10 minutes. Also, power BI service allows to customize time selection only 7-8 times a day whereas, I need to set time for auto-refresh at every 10 minutes interval.

Kindly suggest me how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're desperate for a 10 minute refresh, you cannot do that.

The best you can do is use Azure Analysis services / SSAS to connect to the JSON, do all the ETL/whatever there, and then direct query to it. You'll have to set the SSAS/AAS to Process very often.

Direct query allows for 15 minute refreshes.